# open url with back button

Tags: ios, url, uiviewcontroller

I have one little truble. 
I want to open URL in my iOS application.

The way I found on the web was :

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

and it works fine, but this approach close my app and open safari without back button to return in my app. How to achieve this?

I would like something like

```
   MFMessageComposeViewController * picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than opening the URL in Safari why not just create a new view controller containing a UIWebView?

Show the view controller, pass in the URL, and load the URL into the UIWebView. Something like this:

```
MyWebViewController *mwvc = [[MyWebViewController alloc] initWithURL:myURL];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:mwvc animated:YES];
```

Then in MyWebViewController:initWithURL

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
[myWebView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

*Safari* is the application provided by *Apple* itself, so one cannot make change in behaviour of *Sarari*.

If you require a *back* button then create your custom `UIViewController` using `UIWebView` and place your back button over there.

For *back* functionality, you can either use `UINavigationController` or `UIViewAnimation`.

Answer (score -1):

To get the control back to main native iOS application, you can URLScheme concept. URLScheme concept gives you unique identifier url of a native iOS application. 
Check this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

It gives you fair idea on the procedure to achieve your requirement.

Comment: This will not work as once Safari has been launched there is no way to get back to your application.

Comment: Its sad to read your comments. This is possible from long back in iOS 3.0 and above. One should not comment without atleast fair knowledge. Please Go through the above link you will get an idea.

Comment: I understand how URL schemes work - what I am saying is that once you have launched Safari from your app there is no way for Safari to then use a URL scheme to call back to your app.